# Local variable or instance field name doesn't match regex '[a-z]+'

Tags: android, regex, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle

After upgrading Android studio to `2.1.2`, my code is littered with warnings when I imported my old project into it. The warnings are :

```
Instance field name doesn't match regex '[a-z]+'
Local variable name doesn't match regex '[a-z]+'
Instance field access is not qualified with 'this'
```

Here's the screenshot.

[image: Local variable or instance field name doesn't match regex '[a-z]+']

If I copy this same class file to another new project, there are no warnings. Only old project shows these warnings.
Here's my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I tried `File menu -> Invalidate caches / Restart`, it didn't help.
I would like to solve the problem instead of ignoring the warnings.
Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is the inspector plugin that raises those issues?

Comment: @SupunWijerathne How to know about that?

Comment: You might find that inspections (the face bottom right corner) -> configure Inspections ??

Comment: @SupunWijerathne Thanks, I opened configure inspections, what do I need to verify next?

Comment: If you can compare the settings of where the warnings are On and Off as you specify in your question, you might be able to find what is the one which gives these warnings and you might be able to disable it. I don't know any easier way. :)

Comment: @SupunWijerathne Thanks a lot, this solved my issue, I had to select `Profile` as `Default` instead of `Project Default`. For some reason new Android Studio had imported wrong settings from the old project. Selecting the `Default` profile made the project to use new settings and the warnings disappeared. Please post this as your answer so I can accept your answer. You can include these screenshots http://imgur.com/a/PFs3B in your answer.

Comment: @Yomesh cool. I have added that as an answer (Y) :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Inspection profile has been changed. You can restore that in this manner.

1. Go to **Inspections** **(the face bottom right corner) ->** **Configure Inspections** or **File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inspections**

[image]

2. You can change the inspection profile by selecting the profile you want from the drop down menu on top left corner

or

Disabling any unwanted inspection from the list.

or

Creating your own inspector profile.

[image]

Comment: @Yogesh Umesh Vaity Please edit me for improvements if any. :)