# Private property name doesn't match regex

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

The following code returns this warning in Kotlin project using Android studio 3.0 on Mac.

```
private val REQUEST_CODE = 11 
private val TAG = "RecentCallsActivity"
```

Private property name 'REQUEST_CODE' doesn't match regex '`_?[a-z][A-Za-z\d]*`' less... (⌘F1)
**Reports private property names that do not follow the recommended naming conventions.**

What is the recommended naming convention ?

I found , a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38951610/local-variable-or-instance-field-name-doesnt-match-regex-a-z#),  that answers how to disable the same.

[image]

**Update:** In some examples , I have seen this usage which removes the warning.

```
class KotlinExampleActivity : Activity() {

companion object {
    val TAG: String = KotlinExampleActivity::class.java.simpleName
}
```

Answer (score 37):

it is a warning and you could ignore it. It bothers you, declare them as `private const`

```
private const val REQUEST_CODE = 11 
private const val TAG = "RecentCallsActivity"

class RecentCallsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
```

Or you could declare the `const val` in a companion object. The main difference between the two approaches Is the in the latter you will create a pointless additional object (the companion).

Comment: You shouldn't ignore it. The warning is there for a reason. But adding a const is the correct approach.

Comment: How do you add `const` within a class?  That's so that each TAG has its own scope in debug logs.

Comment: @scottbiggs use a companion object

Comment: add 'const', then the 'analyze code' report will suggest putting in a companion object.

Comment: Putting it top level also creates a Java object.  So either way you will have a static object.

Comment: Const 'val' are only allowed on top level, in named objects, or in companion objects

Answer (score 12):

Kotlin default to the Java Coding Conventions. So use of lowerCamelCase is suggested for Variables. Full caps naming is suggested for Constant variables.
More info here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Answer (score 9):

I believe it requires you to use camel case style of naming for example, instead of REQUEST_CODE use requestCode or another option is to put it inside a companion object for example

```
 companion object {
        private const val TAG: String = "RecentCallsActivity"
    }
```